# division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

let $D$ and $D'$ be $F$-algebras,where as $F=Z(D)$ is field,and $R:=D\otimes D'$ and $D':=1\otimes D'$ and $D:=D\otimes 1$

show that:   $Z(R)=Z(D')$

I can show that $Z_R(D)=D'$ but I can't show that.
I have not any idea how to deal with it. any suggestions ?

Comment: By $Z({\rm whatever})$, you mean the center?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes,$Z(G)$={$g\in G$| ga=ag for any $a\in G$}

Comment: Just a thought (might be wrong): $Z(R) = Z_R(R) = Z_R(D\otimes D') = Z_D(D)\otimes Z_{D'}(D') = F \otimes_F Z_{D'}(D') = Z_{D'}(D')$. Some equalities are isomophisms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x=\sum_{i=1}^nd_i\otimes d_i'$ is in the center of $D\otimes D'$, and assume that this presentation of $x$ as a sum of elementary tensors has a minimal number $n$ of terms. It follows that the elements $d_i', i=1,2,\ldots,n,$ are linearly independent over $F$, for otherwise we could reduce the number of terms in the obvious way.
 Let $r\in D$ be arbitrary. Using the fact that the sum of the subspaces $D\otimes d_i', i=1,2,\ldots,n$ is direct and comparing the products $(r\otimes 1)x$ and $x(r\otimes 1)$ shows that all the elements $d_i$ must commute with $r$. Therefore $d_i\in Z(D)=F$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Therefore $n=1$. The rest is easy.